# Vectorizing eigen value calculation of 3*3*N matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Currently I am using the following code to obtain eigen values:

```
A = randi(100,3,3,4000000);
eig_vals = zeros(4000000,1); 
for i =1:4000000
    eig_vals(i) = max(eig(A(:,:,i))) ;
end
```

I need help to vectorize my eigen value calculations without using a for loop.

Thanks,
Prithivi

Comment: Your best bet would be to implement [the power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) yourself, then vectorize that computation. You cannot vectorize `eig`. But before you do that: is this really a bottleneck in your program? Vectorization does not necessarily yield a faster program, MATLAB's JIT has become really good in recent years.

Comment: @Chris Luengo, if you have time can you post an implementation of this?

Comment: @Durkee: if I had an implementation I’d post it, but I don’t. I’m sure it is not very complicated to implement, but it would take me more time than I’m able to spend on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can  can calculate eigenvalues of a block-diagonal matrix composed of smaller `[3 x 3]` matrices:

```
C=mat2cell(A,3,3,ones(1,size(A,3)));
B=blkdiag(sparse(C{1}),C{2:end});    % A sparse block diagonal matrix
eig_vals = max(reshape(eig(B),3,[]),[],1);
```

But this may not be the most efficient one. So you can process the data part by part to reduce the time for creation of the sparse matrix:

```
s = 4000;
f = find(kron(speye(s),ones(3)));       % indices for matrix blocks
B = spalloc(s*3,s*3,s*3*3);             % preallocate the sparse matrix composed of 4000 matrices of size [3 x 3]
eig_vals = zeros(4000000,1);           
for k = 0: 4000000/s-1
    B(f)= A(:,:,k*s+1:k*s+s);
    eig_vals(k*s+1:k*s+s) = max(reshape(eig(B),3,[]),[],1);
end
```

Here `s=4000` is not the best chunk size. You can tune it for the best performance.

Comment: Good idea. Reduces the number of loop iterations but doesn’t use too much memory either.